# cannot use import statement for scss files with typescript

Tags: typescript

I have added these declarations to an `index.d.ts` files:

```
declare module '*.module.scss' {
  const classes: { [key: string]: string };
  export default classes;
}
```

But when I try and import a default import like this:

```
import styles from './Application.module.scss';
```

I get this error:

> Cannot find module './Application.module.scss'.ts

Comment: We'll need more info like: what's your project structure to start off...

Comment: It seems `Application.module.scss' is recognized as typescript file.

Comment: Are you using webpack or another bundle manager? can you show us the config?

Comment: I'm using webpack but even vscode does not pick it up

Comment: If you are using angular CLI have you added the style=scss flag?

Answer (score 8):

In order to use SCSS modules in TypeScript, you will need [`style-loader`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/style-loader), [`typings-for-css-modules-loader`](https://github.com/Jimdo/typings-for-css-modules-loader) and [`sass-loader`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader).

Use the following `.scss` rule in your **`webpack.config.js`**:

```
{
    test: /\.scss$/,
    include: [
        path.resolve(__dirname, "src/raw")
    ],
    use: [
        { loader: "style-loader" },
        {
            loader: "typings-for-css-modules-loader",
            options: {
                namedexport: true,
                camelcase: true,
                modules: true
            }
        },
        { loader: "sass-loader" }
    ]
}
```